# POST JSON Firefox extension?

Tags: php, json, firefox, post

I have a PHP script set up to read POST data (JSON POST data to be precise).

Are there any Firefox extensions that I can just define my URL, paste a chunk of JSON code - and have that page then load in the browser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the [Postman client](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm) chrome  extension.

And in case of firefox, you can try [Restclient](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/restclient/).

Hope it helps you.

Comment: RESTCLIENT was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks.